# How to fix Error Code: 1041 on heroku MySql free plan?

Tags: mysql, heroku, out-of-memory

I'm using the free plan of jawsdb mysql provided by heroku, whenever I try to add new columns to a table I get this error :-

```
1041. Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory;
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: You should probably ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com, since it is not about programming. Also check if the question has already been asked. For example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120999/1041-out-of-memory-issue-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You're out of space, it's not a coding or programming error - unless you're seeding your database repeatedly or something.

That means you have basically 3 options:

1. Buy more on space Heroku
2. Make more space on Heroku by deleting unused rows or quantifying them and using only the most valuable
3. Change to a different database that is larger, and connect to it instead of Heroku

If the size of your data shouldn't be exceeding the free allotment, then that means you do have an error somewhere. You can drop your DB (erase it), and then build up the data again by seeding it or copying from a file, etc.